# Find out the element from XML file and make it as parent node to load on Tree view control using LINQ in C#(WinForm)

Tags: xml, winforms

This is my XML File, I need to set the tables element as parent mode and also set other attributes in a view of tree view.

```
 <dsSource>
      <dtTable>
        <name>View_one</name>
        <projectname>Sample</projectname>
        <query> select   KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category,KPI_Sales.Advance,KPI_Sales.Amount,KPI_Sales.Carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece from  ( select  KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category,SUM(KPI_Sales.Advance) Advance,SUM(KPI_Sales.Amount) Amount,SUM(KPI_Sales.Carat) Carat from KPI_Sales /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category)KPI_Sales  Inner Join( select  KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount) Sale_amount,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat) Sale_carat,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece) Sale_piece from KPI_Sales_Stock /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch)KPI_Sales_Stock ON KPI_Sales.Branch = KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch </query>
        <tables>KPI_Sales_Stock,KPI_Sales</tables>
        <measures>KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount,KPI_Sales.Carat,KPI_Sales.Amount,KPI_Sales.Advance</measures>
        <dimensions>KPI_Sales.Category,KPI_Sales.Branch</dimensions>
        <newcolumn></newcolumn>
        <dbname>MehtaJewel</dbname>
      </dtTable>
    <dtTable>
      <name>view_two</name>
      <projectname>Sample</projectname>
      <query> select   KPI_Sourcing.Category,KPI_Sourcing.Date,KPI_Sourcing.Division,KPI_Sourcing.Making_Charge,KPI_Sourcing.Pieces,View_one.Sale_amount,View_one.Amount,View_one.Advance from  ( select  KPI_Sourcing.Category,KPI_Sourcing.Date,KPI_Sourcing.Division,SUM(KPI_Sourcing.Making_Charge) Making_Charge,SUM(KPI_Sourcing.Pieces) Pieces from KPI_Sourcing /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sourcing.Category,KPI_Sourcing.Date,KPI_Sourcing.Division)KPI_Sourcing  Inner Join(  select    KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category,KPI_Sales.Advance,KPI_Sales.Amount,KPI_Sales.Carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece from  (  select   KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category,SUM(KPI_Sales.Advance) Advance,SUM(KPI_Sales.Amount) Amount,SUM(KPI_Sales.Carat) Carat from KPI_Sales /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category)KPI_Sales  Inner Join(  select   KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount) Sale_amount,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat) Sale_carat,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece) Sale_piece from KPI_Sales_Stock /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch)KPI_Sales_Stock ON KPI_Sales.Branch = KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch ) View_one ON KPI_Sourcing.Category = View_one.Category </query>
      <tables>View_one,KPI_Sourcing</tables>
      <measures>View_one_tablevw.Advance,View_one_tablevw.Amount,View_one_tablevw.Sale_amount,View_one_tablevw.Pieces,View_one_tablevw.Making_Charge</measures>
      <dimensions>View_one_tablevw.Division,View_one_tablevw.Date,View_one_tablevw.Category</dimensions>
      <newcolumn></newcolumn>
      <dbname>MehtaJewel</dbname>
    </dtTable></dsSource>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but have you made an attempt at what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using the XML provided.  It uses recursion to produce a treeview.  The recursive method is

```
Private Sub BuildTree(xe As XElement, node As TreeNode)
    Dim cnode As TreeNode
    If xe.HasElements Then
        For Each el As XElement In xe.Elements
            cnode = New TreeNode(el.Name.LocalName)
            cnode.Tag = el
            node.Nodes.Add(cnode)
            BuildTree(el, cnode)
        Next
    ElseIf xe.LastNode IsNot Nothing AndAlso xe.LastNode.NodeType = Xml.XmlNodeType.Text Then
        cnode = New TreeNode(xe.LastNode.ToString)
        node.Nodes.Add(cnode)
    End If
End Sub
```

This was tested using this

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim dsSrc As XElement
    dsSrc = <dsSource>
                <dtTable>
                    <name>View_one</name>
                    <projectname>Sample</projectname>
                    <query> select   KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category,KPI_Sales.Advance,KPI_Sales.Amount,KPI_Sales.Carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece from  ( select  KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category,SUM(KPI_Sales.Advance) Advance,SUM(KPI_Sales.Amount) Amount,SUM(KPI_Sales.Carat) Carat from KPI_Sales /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category)KPI_Sales  Inner Join( select  KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount) Sale_amount,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat) Sale_carat,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece) Sale_piece from KPI_Sales_Stock /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch)KPI_Sales_Stock ON KPI_Sales.Branch = KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch </query>
                    <tables>KPI_Sales_Stock,KPI_Sales</tables>
                    <measures>KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount,KPI_Sales.Carat,KPI_Sales.Amount,KPI_Sales.Advance</measures>
                    <dimensions>KPI_Sales.Category,KPI_Sales.Branch</dimensions>
                    <newcolumn></newcolumn>
                    <dbname>MehtaJewel</dbname>
                </dtTable>
                <dtTable>
                    <name>view_two</name>
                    <projectname>Sample</projectname>
                    <query> select   KPI_Sourcing.Category,KPI_Sourcing.Date,KPI_Sourcing.Division,KPI_Sourcing.Making_Charge,KPI_Sourcing.Pieces,View_one.Sale_amount,View_one.Amount,View_one.Advance from  ( select  KPI_Sourcing.Category,KPI_Sourcing.Date,KPI_Sourcing.Division,SUM(KPI_Sourcing.Making_Charge) Making_Charge,SUM(KPI_Sourcing.Pieces) Pieces from KPI_Sourcing /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sourcing.Category,KPI_Sourcing.Date,KPI_Sourcing.Division)KPI_Sourcing  Inner Join(  select    KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category,KPI_Sales.Advance,KPI_Sales.Amount,KPI_Sales.Carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat,KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece from  (  select   KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category,SUM(KPI_Sales.Advance) Advance,SUM(KPI_Sales.Amount) Amount,SUM(KPI_Sales.Carat) Carat from KPI_Sales /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sales.Branch,KPI_Sales.Category)KPI_Sales  Inner Join(  select   KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_amount) Sale_amount,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_carat) Sale_carat,SUM(KPI_Sales_Stock.Sale_piece) Sale_piece from KPI_Sales_Stock /*FilterRegion*/ group by KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch)KPI_Sales_Stock ON KPI_Sales.Branch = KPI_Sales_Stock.Branch ) View_one ON KPI_Sourcing.Category = View_one.Category </query>
                    <tables>View_one,KPI_Sourcing</tables>
                    <measures>View_one_tablevw.Advance,View_one_tablevw.Amount,View_one_tablevw.Sale_amount,View_one_tablevw.Pieces,View_one_tablevw.Making_Charge</measures>
                    <dimensions>View_one_tablevw.Division,View_one_tablevw.Date,View_one_tablevw.Category</dimensions>
                    <newcolumn></newcolumn>
                    <dbname>MehtaJewel</dbname>
                </dtTable>
            </dsSource>

    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
    Dim node As New TreeNode("Tables")
    BuildTree(dsSrc, node)

    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node)
End Sub
```

Sorry for the VB, but it is easily converted to C#.